# Complete a set of functions to obtain a system.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M^m$ be a $m-$manifold and $C=\{y^1,\dots,y^k:U\subset M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\},\;k<m,$ a collection of functions such that on a point $p$, we have that $dy^1|_p,\dots,dy^k|_p$ is linearly independent on $T^*_pM$. Show that there exist smooth functions $y^{k+1},\dots,y^m$ such that $y^1,\dots,y^m$ is a coordinate system for $M$ on a neighborhood of $p$?

Comment: Your manifold $M$ is given somehow. What are the data describing $M$ in the neighborhood of $p$?

Comment: If $F'(p)$ has rank $k$ at some point, then the derivative matrix has a nonzero $k\times k$ minor, which will remain nonzero in some neighborhood. This shows that the rank of $F'$ will be **at least** $k$ in some neighborhood (i.e. rank is lower semicontinuous). But since $k$ is also the maximal possible rank for a map into $\mathbb R^k$, you get $\mathrm{rank}\, F'=k$ in a neighborhood.

Comment: Concerning 2), I think that after "straightening out" the given collection of maps (so that they become $x^1,\dots,x^k$ on $\mathbb R^m$), you should take $x^{k+1},\dots,x^m$ and reverse the process to plant them back onto $M$.